# java.awt.Graphics, how to define position?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics

So, I've noticed that when overriding JFrame, or JPanel's paint method that the graphics context provided's position is relative to the component.

For example:

```
public class Example extends JFrame {

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel() {
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 25, 25);

        }
    };

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel() {
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
           super.paint(g);
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 25, 25);
        }
   };

    public Example() {
        setTitle("Test");
        setSize(800, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        setLayout(null);

        panel1.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 600);
        add(panel1);

        panel2.setBounds(400, 0, 400, 600);
        add(panel2);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Example();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

The rectangles that are painted are at x25, y25 relative to the component, and not to the screen or top-level window.

I was looking to implement this myself, but haven't seen any method in the graphics class that let's you do this.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if you showed us an image and described in greater detail just what you're trying to achieve. Again, what would your desired output be? I have a feeling that your program could use a non-GUI component (classes that don't extend JPanel or JComponent) light-weight graphical object that can be given to a single drawing JPanel. Not the down-voter by the way, just a curious SO patron.

Comment: Actually, my application uses custom components. The components are painted via a render(Graphics g) method, and input is received through listeners attached to the canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the Method [`Graphics.translate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#translate-int-int-). You can specify an x and y value that all points are translated to. Of course, you should invert it after painting so that the superclass is not affected by the changes.

To circumvent problems made by the superclass, you could also use the `create()` method of the `Graphics` object, paint on the new object, and the call `dispose` *(Thanks to HovercraftFullOfEels to point this out)*.

Comment: This could be dangerous to call in a `paint(Graphics g)` method override.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I needed, thank you.

Also @ Hovercraft, that was just an example, my real application uses a buffer strategy with canvas that paints outside of the EDT.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks, I included that.

Comment: Another option is to clone the Graphics object via `create()` and then dispose of the new Graphics object when done. I also always cringe when I see `paint(...)` overridden and null layouts used.

Comment: Oooo, thank you for that, I think that'll come in handy somewhere else... And yeah, but it was just a quick example I wrote up in like 2 mins :p